# how to run php artisan optimize:clear on laravel dockerized app via kubernetes

Tags: laravel, docker, kubernetes, optimization, routes

I'm using Kubernetes on Digitalocean cloud platform

the deckorized laravel app is running right now

and i need to run  `php artisan optimize:clear` to all pods which are loading the app

how can i do that?

**Edit:**

I got the solution

First step connect to pod container

```
kubectl exec -it  pod_name -- /bin/bash
```

then

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

**or**

```
kubectl exec -it pod_name -- /bin/bash -c "php artisan  route:clear"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build a bash file like the below:

```
#!/bin/bash
PODS=$(kubectl get pods -n my-production | grep php-fpm | awk -F' *|/' '$2 == $3 && $4 == "Running"' | awk {'print $1'} | column -t )
for POD in $PODS
do
    echo $POD
    kubectl -n my-production exec $POD -c php -- php artisan optimize:clear
done

echo "Done!"
```

Comment: I'm a beginner,, so could you explain how to apply this bash file into Kubernetes cluster.. or how to run this code to all pods from terminal?

Comment: You should save it as a file like `optimize.sh` and call it like `./optimize.sh`